# How can I has_and_belongs_to_many multiple instances of the same model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Basically, I want to accomplish something like this:

```
Class Node < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :parents, :class_name=>'Node'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :children, :class_name=>'Node'
end
```

but it isn't working, and I'm not entirely sure the proper way to do this. I'm going to try explicitly defining a join table next and have both use it: If that's the solution, would the column be called "children_id" or "child_id"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is doable, but I strongly recommend using `has_many :through` instead:

```
class Node < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parent_node_links,
    :class_name => 'NodeLink',
    :foreign_key => :child_id

  has_many :parents,
    :through => :parent_node_links,
    :source => :parent

  has_many :child_node_links,
    :class_name => 'NodeLink',
    :foreign_key => :parent_id

  has_many :children,
    :through => :child_node_links,
    :source => :child
end

class NodeLink < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent,
    :class_name => "Node"
  belongs_to :child,
    :class_name => "Node"
end
```

Having a first-class join model makes it much easier to manage the relationships and gives you the freedom to add relevant meta-data at a later point in time.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question although it's good advise. I'm trying to avoid 'later point in time designs, and consider only current requirements.

Comment: @ErnestoE It's seven years later and `has_and_belongs_to_many` is still not worth using. The idea is that the `through:` method is extensible if required, and if never extended it doesn't matter, it operates invisibly. The HABTM approach is not intended to be extended, so you're stuck and have to make dramatic alterations to your schema and code. They're not worth the fuss.

Comment: ok, I see now style-guides, rubocop, etc always advise against HABTM. It hasn't been deprecated though... I've done one use-case, will exercise the change to `:through` to review the effort. Thanks for replying, vote goes up again.

Comment: @ErnestoE I honestly don't know why it hasn't. It's full of "gotchas" that aren't especially well documented. It's a quirk of Rails 1.0 that persists to this day.

Answer (score 15):

```
Class Node < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :parents, :class_name=>'Node', :join_table => "parents_children", :foreign_key => :child_id, :association_foreign_key => :parent_id
  has_and_belongs_to_many :children, :class_name=>'Node', :join_table => "parents_children", :foreign_key => :parent_id, :association_foreign_key => :child_id
end
```

Note that you can rename the join table and foreign keys as long as you set the appropriate foreign key names here.