# model family relationships with ancestory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-design

I looked at acts_as_tree and ancestry gems on github but I don't think they do what I want. I did search but couldn't quite find anything that fit what I was trying.

So, basically just a CMS with pages. pages are title:string and body:text. pages can be nested under other pages and can nest other pages.

So, for example, all these are "pages"

```
hardware
hardware/servers
hardware/servers/server1
hardware/servers/server1/parts/powersupply
```

I can ideally servers.children and get children or grandchildren as well.

so this is fine. and acts_as_tree and etc are fine for this.

But what I'd like to do is this as well for page relationships:

```
hardware/servers/server1
equipment/IT/server1
maintenance/monthly/server1/
```

or

```
friends/sally
coworkers/sally
```

so, I guess I want it to have many parents? something like that. I want to be able to access that same page from a variety of 'paths'.

So I'm not sure what that would look like. would I do a join model of some sort because there's something of a "has_many" where as before it was simply parent_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that having many parents is not going to fit with either of these models. What you want instead is to implement a graph. Based on your description it is probably acyclic, that is it does not have any loops, or in other words, a page is never a child of itself, which can lead to certain optimizations.

The general pattern to use here is a many-to-many relationship between pages. For this you would create a join model between `parent` and `child`.

As an example adapted from a [previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826831/how-can-i-has-and-belongs-to-many-multiple-intances-of-the-same-model):

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parent_page_links,
    :class_name => 'PageLink',
    :foreign_key => :child_id

  has_many :parents,
    :through => :parent_page_links,
    :source => :parent

  has_many :child_page_links,
    :class_name => 'PageLink',
    :foreign_key => :parent_id

  has_many :children,
    :through => :child_page_links,
    :source => :child
end

class PageLink < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent,
    :class_name => "Page"
  belongs_to :child,
    :class_name => "Page"
end
```

That's not going to be as efficient as using Ancestry where there is a lot of information about the relationship cached for you, but if performance was a requirement you could port some of those features to this structure.

Comment: thank you stackoverflow and thank you tadman, that looks like it'll do the trick. i'll give it a go and report back.