# Tree database structure with multiple parents and multiple children

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I know for a tree structure of categories, you can use something like:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children, :class_name => "Category"
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Category" 
end
```

**category db**

- id (integer)
- parent_id (integer)
- name (string)

However, how would you make it so that a Category has multiple parents as well as multiple children? I would think I need to add a child_id (integer), but what does the model look like?

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826831/how-can-i-has-and-belongs-to-many-multiple-intances-of-the-same-model

Answer (score 0):

You can have as many parents and children as you want. Your child_id doesn't belong in the table but only the parent_id.

Let me give you a different example.

A tree has_many leaves and has_many bugs. A tree belongs_to forest and belongs_to person.

So the model would look like this:

```
class Tree < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :leaves
  has_many :bugs
  belongs_to :forest
  belongs_to :person
end
```

The `Tree` table would then have `forest_id` and `person_id` attributes. The `Bug` table would have `tree_id` and the `Leaf` table would have `tree_id` respectively. Let me know if you have more questions.

EDIT:

In order to do a circular reference of a model that is its own parent you should be able to simply do this.

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories
end
```

What would happen here is the `Category` table should get a `category_id` field. You can have as many parents and children as you want within the model as long as the `category_id` reference is setup correctly in your table data. So say you have:

```
name | id | category_id
   a | 1  | 1
   b | 2  | 1
   c | 3  | 1
```

Using ActiveRecord Associations you should be able to navigate through this model. I think the trick would be to setup `Category: a` as its own parent since it is the root.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful response, however, I am still confused in the context of a single model. I want the Category model to have several parents and children of itself.

Comment: Like a circular reference? Not sure how well rails can handle it but I'll update my response so hopefully that helps