# Ruby on Rails - Polymorphic associations + joint table + reference the same model twice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I am having a hard time using polymorphic associations in a joint table where one option could lead to the association of two instances of the same table. I am relatively new to programming so I hope my question makes sense.

Basically, I have 3 models where my aim is to make associations between different products:

- Product
- ExtrenalProduct
- Integration (polymorphic)/joint table

The Integration table will link 2 Products or 1 Product and 1 ExternalProduct

Here is my **migration file**:

```
class CreateIntegrations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :integrations do |t|
      t.references :main_product
      t.belongs_to :integratable, polymorphic: true
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :integrations, [:integratable_id, :integratable_type]
    add_foreign_key :integrations, :products, column: :main_product_id, primary_key: :id
  end
end
```

Here is my **Integration Model**:

```
class Integration < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :integratable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :main_product, class_name: 'Product'
end
```

Here is my **ExternalProduct Model**:

```
class ExternalProduct < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :integrations, as: :integratable
end
```

Here is my **Product Model**:

```
has_many :integrations, class_name: 'Integration', foreign_key: 'main_product_id', dependent: :destroy
has_many :integrations, as: :integratable
```

My question is regarding the way I can query all Integrations from @product. As for now, I have to build a custom method:

```
def all_integrations
    Integration.where(main_product_id: id).or(Integration.where(integratable_type: 'Product', integratable_id: id))
end
```

I would like to be able to do a: @product.integrations (which currently retrieves an empty array)

Any clue on what I am doing wrong or how I could make this code DRY? I feel I am missing something.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: To me a polymorphic association should for real life models: images ... I am not sure that a polymorphic model role should only to be handling relationship with models. Can you be more explicit on why a product should be associated with another product ? Is there a specific purpose for this ? Regarding the `ExternalProduct` I would just build a has and belongs to many relationship with the `Product` model

Comment: Maxence, thanks for your answer.
For the context: I am mapping the integration landscape of specific software types. Similarly to Zapier, I would like my users to know if Product A has an integration with Product B.
Product B can either be in my Product or ExternalProduct model, this is why I am using polymorphic association for the Integration joint table. 
I am using has_many as more independent data will be added later on. I could have used has_and_belongs_to_many but it wouldn't have resolved the polymorphic 'issue' aka same model relationship.

Comment: Well to me both relations should be has_and_belongs_to_many. Using the polymorphism can work but it is a bit convoluted. Have you checked this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826831/how-can-i-has-and-belongs-to-many-multiple-instances-of-the-same-model the answer from PinnyM may work in your case (an has_and_belongs_to_many join table where both sides are the same model). It wouldn't be dryier at all, you would have to check relationships in two different tables, but it feels more intuitive.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. It actually makes sense to break it down in the way you have mentioned... I will implement it in case I fail using a single joint table. I have just discovered polymorphism and would love to push to see if it could work this way before going for 2 tables. However, you are giving me doubts now as I believed the polymorphism way to be the 'cleanest way'... Thanks a lot

Comment: First, you have to rename one of the "has_many :integrations"  association in products model. These could be breaking something. Other thing, For this kind of database i recommend you to use STI (Single table inheritance)

Comment: Hi Erick,
Thanks for your feedback I will adjust it. 
I had a look at STI and yes it would have been a valid option too. It's just that my Product model is much more 'important' than the ExternalProduct model in terms of record size and the ExternalProduct model is only used for my Integration checked feature and shouldn't share behaviour with Product